# Saving a data structure in PostgreSQL table

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I am wondering if there is some way to read/update a data structure into PostgreSQL table "at once" like is possible with files.

```
Public Structure myStuct
    Dim p_id As Integer
    Dim p_myInt As Integer
    Dim p_myString As String
    Dim p_myDecNumber As Double
End Structure
Dim st as myStruct

FileGet (ff, recordnum, st)

OR

st.p_id = 1234
st.myInt = 14
st.myString = "tarzan"
st.myDecNumber = 3.14

FilePut (ff, recordnum, st)
```

Question is if we have table with formed data which is of same type like members of structure "st" wouldn't be possible to insert/update whole structure at some index in the table instead of writing every single member one-by-one like I do now?

Comment: I've added a vb.net tag, because i assume that's what language this is in. Please correct that if i'm mistaken!

Comment: What you want is [object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). Usually, this is provided by a library that is separate from both the database and the language runtime. I have no idea what the obtions are for VB, i'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Tom, It's OK, but question is more closely to PostgreSQL.

Comment: I can see why you would think that, but it really isn't.

Comment: The available approaches are in roughly descending order of sanity: Manually normalize and write to table(s); use an ORM; serialize to `json` or `xml` and write to a `json` or `xml` field in the database; serialize the record to a byte array using language-specific serialization and write that to the DB as a `bytea`.

Comment: Thank's Craig, this is what I call real "workaround" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried postgresql composite types?
E.g.

```
CREATE TYPE myStruct AS (
 p_Id        integer,
 myInt       integer,
 myString    text,
 myDecNumber double precision
);
CREATE TABLE myStructs (
 value myStruct
);
INSERT INTO myStructs VALUES ( ROW(1234, 14, 'tarzan', 3.14) );
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rowtypes.html#AEN7268

Comment: Hi einohr (hr?) Never hear for "composite types" so never use them. I will see if that I can use at way I want. Should I load "composite type" every time I step into program before using it or it maybe stays saved in database for later use?

Comment: @user973238: Postgres automatically creates a composite type for every table you create. These types and types created via `CREATE TYPE` are available inside the database just like any other type - until you `DROP` them. I suspect you don't need any of this and a table with columns of basic types would do a better job for you.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Erwin. Really pity what PG don't have a "structure of basic columns" which can be updated from data structure with same "columns" type. Most of the programming languages support data structures. That can simplify coding a bit...